# no puedo acceder a contar un arreglo en Swift

Tags: swift4

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buenas noches eh tratado de solucionarlo pero no me da los resultados, con otro ejercicio parecido me a resultado con este código

```
let contar = ver.filter({$0 == .buscar}).counter
```

pero este ejercicio no me ah salido. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No te funciona y no te debe ni compilar. El comando para contar no es counter, es count

```
let contar = ver.filter({$0 == .buscar}).count
```

Comment: ya lo solucione con este codigo print(chickens.enumerated().filter({$0.element.breed == .leghorn}).count)      si me equivoque al escribir no me fije el detalle pero gracias por responder.

Comment: @S.Figueroa, estaría bien que le valoraras a Spidvmp su respuesta, ya que ha invertido su tiempo para responderte. Es bueno reconocerlo, ¿vale?. Me alegro que ya lo hayas resuelto. :-)

Comment: perdón soy nuevo en esta plataforma como se valora con el click en verde o no . gracias